# Bank customer churn prediction cross-validation

Tags: r, classification, cross-validation

Given sample of customers of a bank that reflects the characteristics of the clients and whether the bank continues to work with them or not (churn). The sample concerns 10,000 customers, while the files "Train.Data" and "Test.Data" include the  information we need.

My data :

Train Data:

```
> dput(head(Train.Data))
structure(list(datetime_utc = c("2010-01-04 00:00:00", "2010-01-04 01:00:00", 
"2010-01-04 02:00:00", "2010-01-04 03:00:00", "2010-01-04 04:00:00", 
"2010-01-04 05:00:00"), Generation_BE = c(13143.7, 13143.7, 13143.7, 
13143.7, 13143.7, 13143.7), Generation_FR = c(63599, 62212, 62918, 
62613, 62432, 63411), Prices.BE = c(37.15, 33.47, 28, 21.29, 
16.92, 28), holidaysBE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Test Data:

```
> dput(head(Test.Data))
structure(list(datetime_utc = c("2016-10-24 00:00:00", "2016-10-24 01:00:00", 
"2016-10-24 02:00:00", "2016-10-24 03:00:00", "2016-10-24 04:00:00", 
"2016-10-24 05:00:00"), Generation_BE = c(9615.7075, 9626.865, 
9648.0025, 9668.42, 9681.805, 9688.425), Generation_FR = c(45605L, 
44629L, 44073L, 44359L, 44056L, 44799L), Prices.BE = c(44.6, 
40.92, 37.39, 36.4, 33.01, 37.89), holidaysBE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The "Train.Data" must be used for churn analysis and model training and the
"Test.Data" is initially considered unknown and should only be used for
final evaluation of the models developed earlier.

*I must use a classification method to predict churn. I decided to build a classification tree.
The problem im facing is that i can build a classification tree but i cant add cross validation in order to measure the accuracy of my model. I need to build a for loop in cross validation !*

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have sketched a code for you using a loop. As you can only use train data, you can split it into train and test sets and store the results in a vector. Here, I will use logistic regression but the process is the same for other learning technique. I used AUROC to evaluate performance but you can change to other metric if needed. The results will be saved in a vector for the metric and the results of models in a list. Here the code, please complete the dependent variable according to your data:

```
library(ROCR)
#Vectors
auroc <- c()
models <- list()
#Loop
for (i in c(1:10))
{
  print(i)
  d = sort(sample(nrow(Train.Data), nrow(Train.Data)*0.6)) 
  train<-Train.Data[d,] 
  test<-Train.Data[-d,] 
  # PASOS SUCESIVOS
  Model <- glm(DependentVarHere~.,data=train,family=binomial)
  test$score<-predict(Model,type='response',test)
  pred<-prediction(test$score,test$GoodBad)
  discr=performance(pred,"auc")
  AUROC=as.numeric(discr@y.values)
  #Save auroc
  auroc[i] <- AUROC
  #Save model
  models[[i]] <- Model
}
#Print values
auroc
#Print mode
models[which(auroc==max(auroc))]
```